# Thunderbolt dock works through front port, but not back port

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, thunderbolt

I have a Lenovo Yoga c930 and a [Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Gen 2](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2-overview-and-sevice-parts) dock. This dock features two USB C/Thunderbolt 3 ports, let's call them the front one and the back one.

The dock's manual explicitly states the laptop should be connected to the **back** port, however I find that the dock only works (in a sense to be specified below) when connected to the front port. However, I experience issues which I suspect are due to being connected through the front port, so I want to try and get the back port working.

When I connect the laptop to the **front** (not recommended by manual) port:

- (1a) USB devices connected to the dock are seen and usable by the laptop.
- (1b) A monitor connected to the dock's DisplayPort port is seen by the laptop and receives the image correctly.
- (1c) The laptop charges at a slow rate (so slow that it decharges while playing a game).
- (1d) I experience occasional USB issues (USB functionality ceases suddenly until I reboot).

When I connect the laptop to the **back** (recommended by manual) port:

- (2a) USB devices connected to the dock work.
- (2b) The same monitor connected to the same DisplayPort port **does not** work. The output of `xrandr` claims to see it and says it's connected, and I can see it in the Ubuntu display settings, but the monitor itself says "No signal". However, if I boot into Windows 10, I get an image on the monitor no problem.
- (2c) The thunderbolt dock itself does not seem to be seen by the system. For example, if I run `boltctl`, the output says the dock is disconnected, as does the Thunderbolt settings manager in the Ubuntu settings.
- (2d) The laptop charges, possibly faster than when connected via the front port, but I'm not sure.

I am willing to chalk up problems (1c) and (1d) to using the wrong port on the dock. Therefore I am interested in fixing problems (2b) and (2c).

### Additional information obtained after this question was posted:

- **05/06/2021** I booted into Windows and used the pre-installed "Lenovo Vantage" program to download and install a BIOS update. I then downloaded and installed the driver and the firmware update at [this](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2-overview-and-sevice-parts) link. No change in behavior.
- **06/06/2021** I made a live USB stick of Ubuntu 20.04 (i.e. the same version I'm using currently) and booted into it in "Try Ubuntu" mode. The back port works! That is, USB devices continue to function (tested a mouse and a hard drive), and the laptop charges, but now the monitor connected through DisplayPort also gets an image. However, `boltctl` does not see the dock. This makes me suspect that the back port of the dock is in fact USB C and not Thunderbolt 3 (although I don't know enough about either protocol to really know if that statement even makes sense). Of course, when I boot back into my usual Ubuntu 20.04 install, the problems have not been fixed. As far as I know, I am using the latest version of 20.04 (the About page in the settings says 20.04.2).

Comment: Do you have firmware V3.1.69 installed?

Comment: @heynnema How would I check that?

Comment: If you download the updater application, it'll probably tell you as part of its process.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I need a little more information. Are you talking about something I should be downloading from the Lenovo website? I found [this](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-c930-13ikb/downloads/driver-list/) page, but all the software seems to be for Windows.

Comment: Yes, but go to the link that you provided in your question. At the bottom of the page are the downloads for the dock. And yes, they may require Windows to install. If you don't have Windows, either take the downloaded firmware updater to a Windows machine to do the upgrade, or you might try using http://www.freedos.org/.

Comment: @heynnema Thankfully I kept Windows installed on this machine in case of a situation like this. So you're saying I should boot into Windows, and download and run the firmware update?

Comment: Yes. And also install the Windows updated driver for it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into Windows.

Go to https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265-thinkpad-thunderbolt-3-dock-gen-2-overview-and-sevice-parts and download the Windows driver V10017 updater, and the firmware V3.1.69 updater.

Install them. **POWER CYCLE the dock**. Test the dock functionality from Windows using the rear port.

Boot back into Ubuntu and retest.

**Update #1:**

Updating the kernel from 5.4.x to 5.8.x fixed the problem. Ubuntu 21.04 would have also fixed the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked. It's hard to know if I did it right of course, since I can't really test it under Windows (because the dock already worked fine under Windows to begin with).

Comment: @JackM Did the installer show you what version was there to start? Did the installer say that it completed properly? Does the back port work under Windows? Does the back port now work under Ubuntu?

Comment: There's no change in behavior - i.e. all bullet points in my question remain true, including that the back port continues to work under Windows. The installers completed successfully, but they were very standard InstallShield wizard things that didn't give any special information. I will reboot into Windows and see if I can find the firmware version anywhere.

Comment: I think the first time I made a mistake and accidentally ran the driver installer twice. I ran the firmware update program and it indeed had a slightly confusing screen telling you (I think, either that or it's just badly translated from Mandarin) what the current version is. However, I ran it twice (rebooting in between) and it showed exactly the same thing, so I'm no longer sure it's installing correctly (although it certainly says it is).

Comment: @JackM POWER CYCLE the dock, and plug the back port to the computer, and see if it works with Ubuntu. Remember to POWER CYCLE it. Unplug it from its DC power brick, count to 10, and replug it.

Comment: No change. Both power cycling it with the laptop connected, and power cycling it with the laptop disconnected and then reconnecting it. `boltctl` shows `Disconnected` the entire time.

Comment: @JackM  What version Ubuntu? Can you make a Ubuntu 21.04 Live USB flash key, boot to it, and see if there's any difference?

Comment: @JackM Have you done the appropriate boltctl commands to list and authorize the dock? See `man boltctl`. Do `sudo boltctl list -a` and `sudo boltctl authorize UUID`.

Comment: Yes, I authorized the dock through the UI when I first connected it a few weeks ago. `boltctl` shows `authorized` when the dock is connected to the front port. When connected to the back port it shows `disconnected` and complains that the dock is disconnected if I try to run `boltctl authorize <uuid>`. `sudo boltctl list -a` doesn't list anything else when connected to the back port.

Comment: I tried 21.04 and the monitor works through the back port. However, `boltctl` still lists the dock as disconnected. Actually it doesn't display it at all, presumably because I never explicitly authorized it while connected to the front port. I'm starting to wonder if the back port on this dock is Thunderbolt at all... maybe it's just USB C? In which case maybe the issue is with Ubuntu 20.04 and DisplayPort over USB C.

Comment: I have edited all of this information into question. A mod should probably delete these comments.

Comment: @JackM Above you say that you tried 21.04 and it worked via the back port. However in your edit to the question, you write 20.04. Which is it? Also, you may have to connect to the front port and "un-authorize" devices, reconnect to the rear port, and re-authorize them there? And, although I don't recommend it, you can delete comments yourself... but it's good to leave them for other readers to be able to follow along. We're making some progress.

Comment: I tried both. Initially 21.04, then later 20.04. I only included 20.04 in the comments since, if it works on the current version, the fact that it also works on a later version seems redundant. Re-authorizing the dock from the back port doesn't make sense, since boltctl can't even see the dock when it's connected to the back port.

Comment: @JackM re: *"if it works on the current version, the fact that it also works on a later version seems redundant"*... not necessarily, as improvements in the thunderbolt support may be in the 21.04 version.

Comment: Turns out the reason the fresh 20.04 install worked was because 20.04 is on kernel 5.8 these days, and I was still on 5.4. I fixed the problem by upgrading the kernel.

Comment: @JackM Then it should have worked with Ubuntu 21.04... and we did try that, yes? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by upgrading from kernel 5.4 to kernel 5.8.

To check to see which kernel version you are on, run `uname -r`. Mine said `5.4` (plus change). To upgrade the kernel, you can run:

```
apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

(This installs "HWE" which enables your distro to install the latest kernel... or something. I don't really understand it, you can begin [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343919/thunderbolt-dock-works-through-front-port-but-not-back-port) to learn more)

After installing that and a reboot, the back port of the dock began working immediately. I currently have a monitor, USB mouse and keyboard, hard drives and charging all working. The charging problem is also fixed: running a video game while connected to the dock no longer decharges the laptop. We'll see if any other problems arise, but the specific problem in the question is fixed.

I should note that **boltctl still displays the dock as disconnected**. You might also find that it just produces empty output, if you're in a similar situation to me. So this apparently is not a bug.

**If you are in a similar situation** and would like to test to see if this is likely to fix your problem before upgrading the kernel, I recommend downloading the latest 20.04 ISO from the Ubuntu website, making a live USB stick from it, and booting into Ubuntu from there.

Comment: The Ubuntu 21.04 that we tried should have also fixed the problem, yes?

Comment: @heynnema It did fix the problem. But I preferred to just upgrade my kernel rather than the whole distro. For other users, upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04, or even just the latest version of 20.04, should fix it. Thank you for your help, by the way. It was the suggestion to try a live boot that got me on the track to figuring out the issue.